# Unit Testing for NSError's

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, testing, core-data

Hallo,

I am trying to set up some unit tests for code that accepts an *NSError as an argument.  If there is a validation problem, then the object is not saved and the NSError condition is set.

My method is:

```
- (BOOL)validateConsistency:(NSError **)error {

    ... code omitted for brevity ...

    if (errorCondition == YES) {
        NSMutableDictionary *errorDetail = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [errorDetail setValue:@"Validation failed " forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"myDomain" code:100 userInfo:errorDetail];
        return nil;
    }
    ...
}
```

Once I've created the conditions that should generate this error, how can I STAssert/test for it in my unit tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing this slightly wrong in two places:

- You're returning nil when you mean to return NO
- You're not checking `error != nil` before assigning to it. It is legal to pass nil as your NSError pointer to mean "I don't care."

Once you fix those, you can test the working case with

```
STAssertTrue(validateConsistency:nil, ...)
```

For error conditions, you'd just do it this way:

```
NSError *error;
STAssertFalse(validateConsistency:&error, ...); // Make sure we failed
STAssertEqual([error code], 100, ...); // Make sure the code is right; we can assume the domain is right, or you could check it.
```